# What does the value in splunk log event signify?

Tags: http, protocols, splunk

This might be a noob question, but please bear with me...I tried googling it and cannot find any relevant answer to this.

In Splunk, for a event log as --

> 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2011:00:00:30 -0500] "GET /test.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 **333**
>   127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2011:00:00:30 -0500] "GET /test.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 **539**
>   127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2011:00:00:30 -0500] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 **8767**

What does the value in bold signify and how is it used to understand the log in splunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those look like [Apache access logs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html), and that column is the response size in bytes (excluding headers). Are you indexing apache logs? Or is this from an internal index in Splunk?

Comment: Thanks Larry, this helped.